# Iterative Solver not solving

Tags: vba, excel

So I want to run a solver on multiple bits of data. I've figured out a large portion of it (except for some copy-pasting that's going poorly...), but I'm stuck on the solver aspect - it's claiming to solve in under a second, when normal manual solver takes a few minutes.

```
Sub Solver()
'
' Solver Macro
' For solving once we have the data

'

    SolverReset

        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$1", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"

            SolverOk SetCell:="$A$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$2:$A$41", _
        Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

End Sub
```

A1 = sum(A2:A42)
D1 is an if statement involving sumproduct of the variables and other conditions. If true, =1, otherwise, =0. Clearly I'd like all of the conditions to be true, and for it to be 1, for the solver to throw out a "it works"

Expected behavior: Solver takes its sweet time figuring out a solution
Current behavior: Solver sets up the problem, then immediately goes onto the next problem to set up.

Am I screwing up my VBA code somehow? Or is it more to do with how my data is moving over?

Comment: Want to provide the workbook for analysis? I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: Solver has an Iterations property which limits how many times it can iterate before returning. Try setting it to something much higher than the default of 100: Iterations:=1000

Comment: It's not how many times the solver tries - I'm running multiple datasets through the solver. But it doesn't want to keep the constraints, or follow the constrains while solving. As for providing the workbook, I'm unable to. I've identified the code that isn't working as this particular piece of code